# Set the HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler's expectedResponseType to a Page

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-integration, spring-data-rest

I'm using a MessagingGateway to perform HTTP calls to another service. 
This endpoint returns a slice of the data (using Pagination), the problem is that the returned result, is of type [Page](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html) which is an interface. I know that the implementation of that interface is a class of type [PageImpl](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageImpl.html) but the problem is that when I'm trying to deserialize it, this class doesn't have any default constructor so it fails. I can create a POJO that contain the property needed and that will solve the problem, but I was wondering if there is any spring-trick that allow me to solve this in a better way.

This is an example of my message gateway configuration:

```
    Map<String, Expression> uriVariableExp = getDefaultEndpointProperties(host, apiKey);
    SpelExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();

    uriVariableExp.put("parameter1", parser.parseExpression("payload.parameter1"));
    String endpoint =
            "{host}/resource?parameter1={parameter1}";

    HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler gateway = new HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler(endpoint, getRestTemplate());
    gateway.setRequiresReply(true);
    gateway.setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.GET);
    ParameterizedTypeReference<Page<ResourceModel>> typeReference = new ParameterizedTypeReference<Page<ResourceModel>>(){};
    gateway.setExpectedResponseTypeExpression(new ValueExpression<>(typeReference));
    gateway.setUriVariableExpressions(uriVariableExp);
    return gateway;
```

As you can see, the expectedResponseType is my problem, I tried with the `PageImpl` but this throw the error of no constructor found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no such a built-in trick. Even worse: you client `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` must not know about the model of the server and not have any Spring Data jars in its classpath. From big height that REST service should not return such a model into the response. Not only your application may be client to that.

Since you have already such a problem you just don't have choice unless introduce some VO POJO to be able to deserialize `Page` properly, or implement your own `HttpMessageConverter` to have a hook to instantiate the `PageImpl` as it is required by the Spring Data.

Comment: Now that you point that the REST service should not return such a model, I'm wondering if it was a good decision to expose repositories in spring data rest, they do return a "Pages". Since they are doing it, I was hoping it can be consumed from other spring-* frameworks like spring integration.

Comment: Well, maybe you should follow with the Spring Data REST recommendations and use `new PagedResourcesType<Resource<ResourceModel>>() {}` instead? See samples there https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/rest. Really not sure that we should add anything as out-of-the-box into Spring Integration because there is no guaranty how would you like to represent that model.

Comment: I was just looking at the code and saw the PagedResources class. Thanks for the help, I will revisit our services pagination strategy, since it seems to be really wrong by exposing `Page` implementations as you well point out.